# change install path in php composer

Tags: php, installation, composer-php

```
{
    "name": "raminious/user",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name":  "",
            "email": ""
        }
    ],

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "raminious\\user\\": ""
        }
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

Above composer.json will copy the package too: **app/vendor/raminious/user**
But I need my packages (that are modules) create to app/vendor/raminious/**modules**/user

How could I change the json file to achieve this? 
Is it possible with composer?

Comment: have you read this ? https://jtreminio.com/2012/10/composer-namespaces-in-5-minutes/